# Orange - Invalid attribute flag 't'

Tags: orange

After importing a CSV via the file widget, I am prompted with a "Invald attribute flag't'". I reviewed the data and did not find any abnormalities that would prompt such an error. I also have not been able to find related articles elsewhere. 
[File - Configuration Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUmIL.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're specifying `t` as `time` in the third row of a [three-line header](https://orange-visual-programming.readthedocs.io/loading-your-data/index.html#three-row-header-format), then you should be specifying it on the second row instead. If you're not trying to achieve that, then just put two blank lines after your CSV header.